# Cannot Restart Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, opengl-es

I am developing a simple 3D presentation engine running on OpenGL ES 2 in Android.

I have two activities: a main launcher activity, wich is a standard android activity, no OpenGL, that let's the user choose what presentation to see.
The other activity is where the OpenGL engine runs. Everything is fine the first time, but nothing seems to happen afterwards.
Sometimes an ANR happens, sometimes nothing, some other times the entire screen of my phone glitches out (which is super-weird). What I think I'm missing is the correct way to stop an activity and unload all of its resources.

I'll post some code regarding Activity start and activity shutdown:

**Start render activity:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(baseActivity.this, RenderActivity.class);
baseActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

**Stop activity:**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    Log.wtf("Render", "Finishing activity...");
    m_render.onDestroy(); //My render control class shutdown method
    if(metaioSDK != null){ //also using metaio for tracking
        metaioSDK.stopCamera();
        metaioSDK.delete();
        metaioSDK = null;
    }
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is your logcat saying?

Comment: Nothing... just some trace writing